# Given random quantum behavior, how are qubits expected to be coaxed to produce a meaningful output in a quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-computing

My understanding of qubits is that their power lies in the fact that they "can have many states at once."  But how would one go about taking advantage of this to get anything that relates to a concrete question/input/program and a meaningful output?  My understanding is that the many states disappears once a measurement is taken, so I don't understand why entanglement would help because there is no additional information from an entangled pair once you know the state of one.  In other words, how are quantum computers supposed to carry out more of a meaningful result than old soothsayers that threw bones for answers.  Yes, the positions of the bones are randomly placed in one of many possible positions but how is this supposed to actually meaningfully relate to a computational program.  I understand how computer gates work to create logic in traditional silicon computers.  But they don't behave randomly.  How is random behavior of cubits and the quantum world in general supposed to yield any useful result?  The power seems to be based on the multistate randomness but why is this random state thought to somehow provide anything more than random output?  Please answer for the type of computer google is building - not DWave "quantum" computers.

Comment: This isn't (yet!) a practical programming problem, so doesn't belong here.

Comment: Where does it belong?

Comment: This question is more on-topic for Quantum Computing StackExchange https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Randomness does not equal uselessness. We also have traditional randomized algorithms that run on classical computers - would you say they can't produce a useful result just because they are not deterministic?

Quantum computing algorithms manipulate the state of the system in a way that makes measuring the correct answer in the end highly probable and any incorrect answer - highly improbable. Some algorithms, like Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm, do it so well that the probability of measuring correct answer is 100%, so even though probabilities are involved in the algorithm description, they actually are deterministic.

---

Let's look at Grover search as an example - this is an algorithm that searches for a solution to an equation f(x) = 1. You'll get your answer x by measuring several qubits (it's a lot more common than using qudits). You start with these qubits in equal superposition - if you do a measurement at this stage you won't get anything useful indeed, since you'll get an arbitrary result with equal probability, and it will probably not be an answer to your problem. Grover's algorithm is a sequence of steps that modifies the state of the system so that superposition of the results is not equal any longer - the probabilities of states that solve your problem are amplified, and the probabilities of states that don't solve it are reduced. This means that measurement results are still random, but the probability of getting a correct answer is much higher than what you started with.

Comment: If you are looking for a random number generator, I suppose qubits are great.  How can random data do anything useful like the factorization of large numbers which is often in the news?

Comment: Sorry, I can not explain Shor's algorithm in 570 characters that StackOverflow allows for a comment :-) Quantum computing algorithms are more sophisticated than random number generation; I would suggest to read some kind of intro to quantum computing and to figure out how Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm works (which is a deterministic algorithm even if it is defined in terms of probabilities) as a good first step for answering your question.

Comment: Thank you Mariia for the time you have taken to respond to me.  I have read some of Shor's algorithm although it is obviously complex.  But before thinking of something mathematically so complicated, simply based on the properties of qubits or qudits described by quantum mechanics, how does one extract a useful answer from a qubit or qudit that contains multiple states all at once.  Say a qudit holds 0,1,2,3 and a "programming question" asks for an answer that is one of these numbers - how does this translate to a particual answer of only of these states?  How is something specific determined?

Comment: I added an example of Grover search to the answer (can't really squeeze it into a comment) - hope that helps!